# Run the DataTree exampe of D3JS

Tags: http, d3.js

I am trying to test the example of the DataTree of D3Js and I just copied and pasted the code in: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329447 . I saved the TreeData.json in my C drive and changed the `d3.json("treeData.json", function(error, treeData)` to `d3.json("C:\treeData.json", function(error, treeData)` But I can not see any results. But once I hard code the json file into the program it works fine. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: The browser does not have permission to do Cross origin requests. The origin is where your webserver runs. Just copy the treeData.json file in the same directory where you have the html file. Make sure to run a web server otherwise most brwosers won't let you access any file.

Comment: Actually I am using a web application in visual basic and I put that file in the bin folder of the solution. But still do not get anything.

Comment: Probably still the cross domain thing. To test, try using firefox and see if it works (it has been a bit more tolerant than Chrome in the past)

Comment: Can you look in the javascript console what the error message is ?

Comment: GET http://localhost:62241/treeData.json 404 (Not Found)
index.html:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I get these two errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615033/running-treedata-example-d3js