# Running TreeData example D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to test the example of the DataTree of D3Js and I just copied and pasted the code in: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8329447 . I saved the TreeData.json in my C drive and changed the d3.json("treeData.json", function(error, treeData) to d3.json("C:\treeData.json", function(error, treeData) and I get the error of "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" by looking at the javascript console. But once I hard code the json file into the program it works fine. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Please *do not* post the same question twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run the DataTree exampe of D3JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596120/run-the-datatree-exampe-of-d3js)

Comment: This was my own question and nobody answered to that!

Comment: Still no answer for this question!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that web pages can't read your C drive you need to put the relative path to your json file in you project.

Easiest way to do this is to treeData.json file in the project folder with your treeData.json

Comment: I tried that. I am using Visual Studio and put it in the project folder. I also tried the bin folder. I am assuming I am putting it in the wrong spot. Should it be in the project folder or bin folder or...?

Comment: What IDE your using shouldn't make a difference, your treeData.json has to be in the same folder as your index.html

Comment: Still having the same issue :(

Comment: Probably a [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) issue then, What browser are you using ? I think firefox is fine with loading local file through JS, Chrome isn't as friendly. Best bet is to run it on a server.

Comment: Well then your going to need to put it on a server just run something like python simple web server in that folder on localhost

Comment: Can I use IIS Express since I am using .NET applications?

Comment: Sure but I've never used IIS so I can't help yo with it further if it doesn't work

Comment: Actually it is not working. What other servers can I use? I do not have python running on my machine so I appreciate if you suggest something else?